# what is the solution of this limit. I am having a little bit trouble

Tags: limits

$F(x)$ is $x\cdot \tan{1\over x}$ ?What is the value of limit of $F(x)$ where $x$ tends to $0$.  Can I also do it using squeeze theorem here? If yes how ? If not why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have equivalently to consider $\lim_{x\to \pm \infty}\tan(x)/x$. It does not exist, indeed on the one hand
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\tan (2k\pi)}{2k\pi}=0,
$$
and on the other hand, for each positive integer $k$, it holds
$$
\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\frac{\tan(2k+\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)\pi}{(2k+\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)\pi}=\infty.
$$

Comment: why my considerations are wrong

Comment: @ShubhankarMondal You do not show any real considerations. (Just accept that the limit does not exist.)

Comment: Usually you use squeeze theorem to prove that a limit actually exists, and this is not the case

Comment: you mean to say that my function is not real at x tends to 0

Comment: I would just say that "$f$ is undefined at $0$"