# Limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{1}{x} \sin(1/x^2)$

Tags: limits

My f(x) is (1/x)sin(1/(x^2))? Limit when x tends to 0? Can i also do it using squeeze theorem here? If yes how ? If not why?

Comment: This is extremely similar to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1601850/97236). Maybe you can use a similar idea here as in the correct answer there by @jordan?

Comment: You should show some effort of your own. The answers on your previous questions can help you with that.

Comment: i used my effort and my answer is DNE .. is it correct

Comment: What happens when $x_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(n+\frac12)\pi}}$ ? What happens when $x_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi}}$ ?

Comment: it does not exist if n is very very large so that x tends to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $u=\frac{1}{x}$ our argument inside sine becomes a $u^2$.Our expression then becomes $u\sin (u^2)$. Now as $x\to 0$, $u \to \infty$. We can see that this expression goes off to infinity and hence the limit does not exist.

Comment: sir I have tried it.. whats the answer

Comment: @ShubhankarMondal Try harder and come back after some time if you get stuck. This also to show your own results.

Comment: @ShubhankarMondal edited in the answer. Also, the name is El Chapo not sir.

Comment: el chapo .. my answer is DNE.. is it correct

Comment: Yes it is correct.